# How to resolve "Error: Cannot find module 'gulp-browserify'"

Tags: macos

I tried to run my files with gulp, and it showed:

Last login: Fri Dec  5 11:09:12 on ttys001
Macs-MacBook-Pro:responsive mac$ gulp

```
Error: Cannot find module 'gulp-browserify'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/mac/Desktop/responsive/gulpfile.js:3:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

What should I do?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've just reinstalled gulp (and all required modules) globally and locally; like:

```
sudo npm install -g gulp gulp-watch gulp-stylus gulp-file-include browser-sync kouto-swiss gulp-browserify browserify
```

and then in project folder:

```
npm install gulp gulp-watch gulp-stylus gulp-file-include browser-sync kouto-swiss gulp-browserify browserify
```

and that helped for me